# AccountKit : how to if a user change phone number

Tags: android, ios, account-kit

I'm using AccountKit to implement SMS login in a iOS and Android apps and that works fine ... but now i'm thinking how i should manage the case when an already registered user logout ,changes sim and phone number, and then log in again ... how could i detect he is the same user that was already registered before ?